# invalid literal for int() with base 10 with a name and two numbers

Tags: python

I'm having trouble entering data I keep getting the error "invalid literal for int() with base 10"

```
    def strings_to_ints(linelist):
    outputlist = []
    for item in linelist:
        outputlist.append(int(item))
    return outputlist


def process_line(line):
    global box_count, ship_class
    linestrings = line.split()
    name = linestrings[0]
    linevalues = strings_to_ints(linestrings[:1])
    quantity = linevalues [0]
    ship_class = linevalues [1]
    box_count = box_count + quantity
    order_price = compute_price(quantity)
    discounted_price = compute_discounted_price()
    tax = compute_tax(discounted_price)
    ship_cost = compute_ship_cost(quantity)
    billed_amount = discounted_price + tax + ship_cost
    outlist = [quantity, order_price, compute_discount(), tax, ship_cost, billed_amount]
    return name, outlist


def enter_data():
    global order_count
    line = input('Enter Name, Quantity, and Ship Class: >>> ')
    name, outlist = process_line(line)
    order_count = order_count + 1
    print(name, outlist))
```

I know I that the name should somehow be separate from the numbers but I can't figure out where to do this.

I added the most of code, all of the relevant parts I think. Hopefully, it's easier to understand

Comment: **Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].** As an aside, is the use of `global` really necessary here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
linevalues = strings_to_ints(linestrings[:1])
```

should be:

```
linevalues = strings_to_ints(linestrings[1:])
```

Assuming that both Quantity and ship class are integers, and are space separated

i.e.
Test 1 2

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried that but I get "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: Can you add the error? and what you're doing to get it. You've got the program so you can only enter a value of 1 without receiving "invalid choice", due to if choice = =1

Comment: Is there further code missing? As the enter data proc appears to work for me with the modification. So i'm guessing your error is elsewhere.

Comment: I did what you suggested and tried inputting it in a different way and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Whithout understanding all of your code, I think that the problem is that `linestrings[:1]` is an array containing at most the first element of `linestrings`. If you want all but the first, use `linestrings[1:]` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately I get "IndexError: list index out of range" when I try that

Comment: Well, what precisely do you input?

Comment: Well if I run your code and enter 'john 10 1' (whithout the "'"s), I get john [10, 155.0, 0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5].

Comment: Okay I get that too now actually. Thank you!